# Server side state management in Next js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When use any hook in next js this component will become client side and also if we use the React Context or Redux the need to wrap complete App while configuration. When we wrap then it also becomes the client side.
Then what are the benefits of next js if it becomes the client side instead of server side? Or is there any library to manage the state on the server side?

When I wrap the app with provider then it will becomes the client side. Then will we get the benefits of server side rendering?

Comment: i believe this will help you understand it more: https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for managing state on the server-side, there isn’t a common library because it’s often not needed. Server-side state would be lost as soon as the request ends anyway. If you need to persist state across requests, consider using a database or some form of storage that’s accessible from the server.

I hope this helps! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35773233)

Answer (score 0):

That's what Next docs says: "You should render providers as deep as possible in the tree"
But instead of using context you can try to use queryParams for example.